# Cannot clone forked repo - seems to be a key conflict

Tags: git, github

I have been sent a code test from a prospective employer. It was a github repo I was supposed to fork, work with, and then upload.

I was able to fork the repo, but when I tried to clone it, I got an error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/blah-username.git/'
```

I have a separate github account for work and I believe that the ssh key on my machine may have conflicted with my normal account. I requested a new ssh key and uploaded it to github. That did not solve the problem.

If I run the following command in the terminal where I changed the key, I get the following results.

```
ssh-add -l
(key) (proper email)
```

However, running that same command in a separate terminal returns the following:

```
ssh-add -l
(key) (work email)
```

This basically cost me an interview and several hours of my time. Not sure what to do here, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe that the ssh key on my machine may have conflicted with my normal account

No, your SSH key is completely irrelevant to the error message shown, which complains about authorization for `https://github.com/username/blah-username.git`. That is not an SSH URL, so it doesn't need SSH authorization: it is an HTTPS URL and it needs HTTPS URL.

I'd say you gave the wrong `clone` command. For example, you said

```
git clone https://github.com/username/blah.git
```

But you should have said

```
git clone git@github.com:username/blah.git
```

When you go to GitHub and click the Code button, it tells you what to put after `git clone` — with a choice between SSH and HTTPS:

[image]

[image]

GitHub has gotten really strict about HTTPS authentication; basically they are trying to phase it out, and if you must use it, you should use 2FA, or a one-time 2FA password, or a personal access token. You may never have set any of that up, so your attempt to use HTTPS authorization failed. If you had used SSH, it would probably have just worked.